# Spring data jpa join query using @query in repository

Tags: spring-data-jpa

How to write join query using @query in spring data jpa without mapping (@oneToOne or manyToOne) between two entities class?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not supported by JPA. Therefore Spring Data JPA can not join unrelated entities.

Hibernate 5.1 introduced [explicit joins](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-explicit-join). You can leverage this feature by adding a [custom repository implementation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/1.9.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `@Query(value = "", nativeQuery = true)` ?